# Sonar 6.x LTS release schedule

Tags: sonarqube, release, lts

We would like to upgrade our Sonar setup to 6.x but waiting for LTS release. Is there any update on when Sonarqube LTS (6.x) release is scheduled?

Also, we would like to understand major differences between Sonarqube 4.5.7 & Sonarqube 6.x in terms of support for Java/maven/msbuild/fxcop versions and other major features that 4.x users should be aware of.

Comment: So normally a release is every 2 months, if I am not mistaken, and 6.7. is the next LTS, if I am also not mistaken

Comment: And for the differences, you should check the release notes. But eg. Rails got removed and replace with java, but most of the terms of support is a plugin question, and you should check the plugins specially

Your question is pretty generic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release of 6.7 LTS is planned for this fall. But you *cannot* upgrade directly from 4.5.7 to 6.7; you must first go through the intervening (current) LTS: 5.6.6.

For a summary of the differences between 4.5.7 and 5.6.6, see [this blog post](https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-5-6-lts-in-screenshots/). If you want more details, you should consult the release notes, as Simon noted in the comments.

When you upgrade to 5.6.6 (why not go ahead & get that out of the way?), you'll find that your custom dashboards are still there, but have been set aside in favor of a hard-coded project homepage. When you get to 6.7, you'll find that custom dashboards have been eliminated entirely, and a new projects page has been provided, as well as a reworked Measures space and countless other improvements.

**Nov 2019 Update:** The current LTS is now [7.9](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/). More information about [the SonarQube LTS model is available here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/lts/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have a enterprise setup being used by many teams and cannot afford to have multiple upgrade in short time. Instead of going for 5.6.6 now wait for some more time to get into 6.7 we will wait for 6.7 release. As you mentioned during upgrade we make sure to move to 5.6.6 first & then to 6.7.  Regarding differences between 4.5.7 & 6.7 versions I would like to understand below points  1. Are View and SQALE plugins still supported in new version? 2. There was a plan to implement FxCop &Findbugs rules in C# & Java plugins. What is the update on this?