# Sonar 7.x LTS release schedule

Tags: sonarqube, release, lts

We would like to upgrade our Sonar setup to 7.x but waiting for LTS release.

- Is there any update on when Sonarqube LTS (7.x) release is scheduled?
- Is there already some URL containing such information?

(i hope it is ok to "impersonate" [the question for the 6.x LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315041) which g.ann was so nice to answer)

If such info would be made available on the interwebs somewhere we would not need to ask here.

cheers and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far I know there is no public schedule available. You can find the latest versions [here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads). SonarQube 5.6 LTS was released in Jul 2016; SonarQube 6.7 LTS in Dec 2017 so it is likely that the 7.x LTS version will be released somewhere in the first half of 2019. The latest SonarQube news is posted [here](https://blog.sonarsource.com/) and you can also follow the [feedback](https://community.sonarsource.com/) channels. On the Google forum (will be moved very soon) you can find messages about pre-releases for example. You can also have look at the [cloud version](https://about.sonarcloud.io/get-started/); that will be updated first.

**Update May 2019**
In a blog SonarSource announced the end of support of [MySQL](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/end-of-life-of-mysql-support/8667), starting from SonarQube v7.9. So there will be one more minor version update before a LTS version is made or they skip v7.8. See [the roadmap page](https://www.sonarqube.org/roadmap/) regarding the new v7.9 LTS version.

Comment: thank you Jeroen, i was silently hoping for G. Ann. to take this one :-) but your reply supplies infos about my second request concerning URLs to find info in. So i will mark it as useful, ty!

Comment: LTS v7.9 coming over early July! https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-whats-new-page-and-lts-target-date/9884

Answer (score 0):

To provide a late answer to a question with an already-accepted answer...

[SonarQube 7.9 LTS was released on 1 July 2019](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-9-lts/) and the next LTS can be expected ~18mo after that<sup>*</sup>. 
More information about the SonarQube LTS model - including the period between new LTSs - is available [here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/lts/)

<sup>*Normal caveats about estimate precision apply. ;-)</sup>